# Validação de formulários MVC - PHP

Tags: php, mvc, formulário

Para validar formulários com os conceitos do MVC, teria que ser no *Controller*, *Model*, ou *View*?
Pesquisando na **internet** vi alguns artigos sobre o assunto, mas alguns recomendam fazer no *model* outros na *view*, a final, posso inserir códigos PHP na *view*? Esse método não fica com o código poluído?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendado usar validação dentro do model, e quanto usar código php na view pode sim, mas somente para renderizar alguns dados vindo do controller. Exemplo, usar foreach/variaveis/for etc para renderizar dados vindo do controller...

Comment: É preciso usar orientação a objetos ou posso recuperar desta forma? `if(isset($_POST['btnExemple'])) {...}` é só uma dúvida básica para um iniciante como eu :p

Comment: @GuilhermeGouveiaAlves não entendi, MVC maioria é feito em Orientação Objecto você usa alguma framework?

Comment: Não estou usando Framework, eu e um amigo que é iniciante também estamos fazendo uma aplicação simples para estudos...

Answer (score 1):

A validação na view é utilizada apenas para evitar uma requisição "inválida", mas essa validação não deve ser confiada já que o usuário pode altera-la.

A validação mais confiável é feita no servidor, essa questão de faze-la no controller ou model é muito conceitual, vai da sua organização/metodologia, em ambos os casos vai funcionar.

Por usar Zend Framework 2, eu criei o costume de criar um objeto para formulário (que vira o form no html) e outro objeto para filtragem e validação dos dados, ambos objetos fazem parte da camada Model, pois contém regras de negócio, mas são manuseados no controller, considero isso uma maneira bem organizada e recomendo.

Segue um exemplo:

```
class ProdutosController
{
    /**
     * Este action insere produto no banco de dados
     */
    public function addAction()
    {
        $requisicao = $this->getRequisicao(); // requisição
        $dados      = $requisicao->getPost(); // dados enviados pelo form

        $entidade = $this->getEntidade; // entidade, mapeamento da tabela produtos do banco de dados
        $model    = $this->getModel(); // model, classe que conversa diretamente com o BD
        $form     = $this->getForm(); // Objeto form para montar formulário HTML

        // Se requisição for post, é porque usuário enviou o formulário
        // caso contrário é GET então ele está visualizando o form de inserção
        if ($requisicao->isPost()) {

            // Injeta objeto que filtra e valida os dados
            $form->setInputFilter($entidade->getInputFilter());

            // Joga os dados enviados pelo form HTML pra dentro do objeto form
            // assim será possível valida-los e outras ações que são feitas pelo objeto form
            $form->setDados($dados);

            // Verifica se o form foi validado com sucesso (executa validações do inputFilter)
            if ($form->isValid()) {

                // hidrata/popula a entidade com os dados que estavam no form
                $entidade->hidratar($form->getDados());

                // insere a entidade no banco de dados
                $model->insert($entidade);

                // Após inserção, redireciona para listagem
                $this->redirect()->toRoute('produtos/lista');
            }
        }

        // Caso requisição não seja POST ou caso validação do form tenha falhado
        // então carregar a view
        // caso validação do form tenha falhado, vai enviar as msgs de erro para a view tb

        // retornar um array é o jeito do Zend de enviar variáveis para a view
        return array(
            'variavel1' => 'valor1',
            'variavel2' => 'valor2',
            'variavel3' => 'valor3',
            'form'      => $form,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Você teria algum exemplo? Sou iniciante com `PHP` e tenho muitas dúvidas.

Comment: @GuilhermeGouveiaAlves adicionei um exemplo com comentários pra facilitar, algumas coisas ali são características do Zend Framework 2, outras são conceitos que você pode usar em qualquer aplicação MVC.

Answer (score 0):

A validação no *controller* não poderia, pois ele só controla a requisição e a *view* apenas mostra o visual para o usuário com qualquer saida de representação de dados. E seguindo o raciocinio que a validação faz parte da "regra do negocio", entao restou para o *model*.

Uma alternativa seria criar um diretorio adicional fora do MVC somente para a validação de formulario chamada *InputFilter*, *Validator* ou como eu costumo usar, ***Filter***

exemplo: 01

```
app/
|___ Model/
|
|___ View/
|
|___ Controller/
|
|___ Filter/
```

E tambem nada impede de criar o diretório dentro da propria "model" salientando que validação faz parte da "regra do negócio"

exemplo: 02

```
app/
|___ Model/
|      |___ Filter/
|
|___ View/
|
|___ Controller/
```