# Regras para Validação de Parâmetros estabelecidos em Banco de dados PHP

Tags: php

Amigos,
Gostaria da opinião e sugestões de vocês com relação a regras de validação por parâmetros estabelecidos em um site.
Tenho 2 tipos de parâmetros, um global, que servira para todo o site, e um chamado produto, que servira para produtos.
São n validações que tenho que fazer, primeiramente tenho que validar para o global, tipo, o cliente so poderá comprar 3 produtos no geral até sua entrega e outros parâmetros. Depois de verificado isso para para os parâmetros dos produtos, tipo o usuário poderá levar apenas 3 unidade de um determinado produto.
São muitas regras que terão que ser comparadas para poder validar os dados.
Gostaria de idéias, sugestões para fazer essas validações de forma eficiente.
Tenho uma tabela chamada parâmetros, onde salvo os parâmetros gerais, e de cada produto, salvo na tabela produtos mesmo
Aguardo a ajuda de todos

Comment: Sua aplicação usa o padrão MVC? É orientada a objetos?

Comment: sem padrão MVC e nem orietada a objetos. Programação estruturada.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, pelo o que eu entendi sua pergunta é mais conceitual do que prática, você está procurando a melhor maneira de fazer essas validações.

Na programação estruturada, eu faria o seguinte:

- Uma função para validar os parâmetros globais
- Uma função para validar os parâmetros de produtos
- Uma outra função que é a função "pai", que processa algumas coisas e chama essas duas funções de validação

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
// $dados são os valores enviados no form
function controller($dados)  // esta é a function "pai"
{
    // alguns processamentos caso você precise
    if (validacaoGlobal($dados) && validacaoProdutos($dados)) {
        // sucesso em ambas validações, exibir mensagem de sucesso
    }
    // caso contrário, algo deu errado e você retornar uma mensagem de erro informativa ao usuário
    // sobre o que aconteceu

}

function validacaoGlobal($dados)
{
    $sucesso = true;

    // faz as validaões, se algo der errado $sucesso vira false;
    // tente implementar uma lógica para elaborar uma mensagem de erro intuitiva caso algo dê errado
    // essa mensagem seria exibida para o usuário

    return $sucesso;
}

function validacaoProdutos($dados)
{
    $sucesso = true;

    // faz as validaões, se algo der errado $sucesso vira false;
    // tente implementar uma lógica para elaborar uma mensagem de erro intuitiva caso algo dê errado
    // essa mensagem seria exibida para o usuário

    return $sucesso;   
}
```

Caso tenha interesse em como isso seria feito com MVC e Orientação a Objeto, [veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113965/21593)

Comment: a estrutura já está dessa forma. São N parametros globais e N parametros de produtos. O Retorno devera no momento em que uma condição não for validada. Acho que não vou ter como sair de muitos ifs e retornar o motivo da falha. 
a pergunta não tem mesmo a ver com código e sim trocar idéias de fazer de forma eficiente. Obrigado pela ajuda, meu pensamento é igual ao seu. Como as regras estão no bd, vou ter que ficar consultando

Comment: @lelopes Não sei se você busca uma regra por vez conforme a necessidade, mas se está fazendo isso, uma melhoria no desempenho seria buscar todas as regras de uma vez só e armazena-las em forma de array ou algo do tipo, assim você economiza queries no banco.